# How to create transparent navigation bar like in new twitter?

Tags: navigation

I want to add navigation bar at the top side of my web site like in new twitter design.
How can I add it? (please see example below...)

[image: http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/2361/twttr.png]

Comment: Have you viewed their source code to see how they did it?

Comment: yes I use firebug but I could not understand how to add it...

Answer (score 0):

There is a div called `top-stuff`. It has the following css:

```
#top-stuff {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 12;
}
```